# Emacs on MacOS - no window detected

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm running emacs 29.1 (installed from homebrew cask) and when I use a task-switcher like [Contexts](https://contexts.co/) the emacs window is detected as "App without windows". Similarly the app I use for tracking my time ([Memory.ai / timely](https://timelyapp.com/)) is unable to detect the title of the emacs window.

The latter is particularly frustrating because the window title is rather helpful when trying to determine which project I was working on.

Here's a screenshot of how this looks with contexts:
[image: Screenshot, showing that Contexts can't show Emacs's window title]

How can I fix that, so that the window title can be properly detected?

Comment: sounds like a bug in Contexts or Emacs. report it as such.